# Pass raw value to onChangeText in React Native

Tags: react-native, formik, textinput

In my react project i am using Formik library. for the input i am using TextInputMask which is other library.

```
export default function Calc() {
return (
    <Formik
        initialValues={{ monthly_rental: '', }}
    >
        {(props) => (
            <View>
                <Text>Monthly rental</Text>
                <TextInputMask
                    type={"money"}
                    options={{
                        precision: 0,
                        separator: ".",
                        delimiter: ",",
                        unit: "£",
                        suffixUnit: ""
                    }}
                    placeholder={"£500"}
                    value={props.values.monthly_rental}
                    includeRawValueInChangeText={true}
                    onChangeText={props.handleChange('monthly_rental')}
                />
            </View>
        )}
    </Formik>
  )
 }
```

The above code work nicely but what i want is on `onChangeText={props.handleChange('monthly_rental')}` set the raw value instead of formatted value.

i have seen this code but i dont now to to implement this

```
onChangeText={(text, rawValue) => {
        this.setState({
          value: text,
          raw: rawValue
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I have find out. In the Formik Library there is a function called `setFieldValue: (field: string, value: any, shouldValidate?: boolean) => void`. [see here](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik)

So my final solution was this :

```
<TextInputMask
  type={"money"}
  options={{
    precision: 0,
    separator: ".",
    delimiter: ",",
    unit: "£",
    suffixUnit: ""
  }}
  style={globalstyles.input}
  textAlign={"center"}
  placeholder={"£500"}
  keyboardType={"decimal-pad"}
  value={props.values.monthly_rental}
  includeRawValueInChangeText={true}
  onChangeText={(maskedText, rawText) => {
    // Set RawText
    props.setFieldValue('monthly_rental', rawText)
  }}
/>
```